# `{{ var }}` syntax from Jupyter notebook is not rendered in Jupyter lab [Python Markdown is missing?]

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

From [jupyter_contrib_nbextensions](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions#installation), there is a handy package called [Python Markdown](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/tree/master/src/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/nbextensions/python-markdown). After following the installation instructions, I got **Jupyter notebooks** to render `{{ var }}` by replacing the whole thing to be the value stored in `var`. This happens in the markdown cells.

Yet, the identical syntax is not working with **Jupyter lab** sessions.
Here goes a side-by-side comparison:

- In Jupyter notebook:
  [image]
- In Jupyter lab:
  [image]

Any thought on enabling such Jupyter magic for Juptyer lab?